# Java - notifyAll() and notify() failed? Is it possible?

Tags: java

This is really weird to me, but looks like notifyAll()/notify() failed in my program.
The code is rather complicated, basically I have three threads A, B, C

A sends request to B and wait() on the request with a 10 secs timeout, when B finishes, it calls notify() to wake up A.

C in a deadloop feeds a lot of strings to A through a queue, A picks up them and prints out. Each time A print out a string it sends a request to B and wait.

So the workflow comes to be:

C keeps feeding a in deadloop

1. A prints out string from C
2. A sends request to B and wait(10)
3. B notify() A
   ......
4. A prints out string from C
   .... again and again ....

This works in first a few seconds. however, after a while I see when B prints out that it has notify() A, A is still waiting because the queue which C uses to feed A is getting increased quickly, and no string gets printed by A. Finally, after 10 secs, A complains the request timeout.

This looks like the notify() failed because B printed out message after it called notify(). Given wait/notify is radical feature of java, I can not believe it will fail. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you *sure* A is "still waiting"? The other possibility is that it *started* waiting *after* the notify, which would be broken code. (You should never wait for something that has already happened.)

Comment: Maybe B have called notify BEFORE A calls wait

Comment: @david "You should never wait for something that has already happened". I love this.

Comment: Maybe B finished its work and called notify() before A called wait()? Anyway, it may be better to use something like a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) to synchronise A and B. It's a lot easier to reason about than wait()/notify(), so you can avoid nasty timing bugs like this.

Comment: Without code its hard to tell are you sure you are locking on the same object for the wait and notify?

Comment: You guys really help me much! Even though I haven't tested, the timing issue that "You should never wait for something that has already happened" seems to be decent answer. I will test tonight and get the results back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

notify() will only work if there is a thread wait()ing for it at that time.

The idiom you should use is to change a state in the same synchronized block as notify()/notifyAll(). In the waiting block, you repeatedly check for the state change.  That way if the notify was triggered too early there is a state change to record it.  Also if wait wakes spuriously it will wait again if the state hasn't changed.

```
public synchronized void notifyReady() {
    ready = true;
    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void waitForReady() throws InterruptedException {
    while(!ready)
      wait();
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. The timing issue has been proved to be cause